# How to merge multiple Numpy array into single array

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I want to merge multiple  2d Numpy array of shapes let say (r, a) ,(r,b) ,(r,c),...(r,z) into single 2d array of shape (r,a+b+c...+z)

I tried np.hstack but it needs the same shape & np.concat operates only on tuple as 2nd array.

Comment: Are you sure that shape[0] are all equal and `np.hstack` didn't work? Try `np.vstack` instead

Comment: can you please tell me the shape of each 2d array and give a simple example also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) or [np.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html). Here is an example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14]])
>>> b = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
>>> b
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])

>>> np.concatenate((a,b), axis =1)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  1],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  2,  3],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  4,  5],
       [ 9, 10, 11,  6,  7],
       [12, 13, 14,  8,  9]])

>>> np.hstack((a,b))
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  1],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  2,  3],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  4,  5],
       [ 9, 10, 11,  6,  7],
       [12, 13, 14,  8,  9]])
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I am new to numpy but I think its not possible. Precondition is 
"The arrays must have the same shape along all but the second axis, except 1-D arrays which can be any length."

Comment: Hi! it works. the condition you mentioned from numpy documentation doesn't mean the way you are thinking. The precondition's meaning is all the dimensions should be same accept the one in which you want to add i.e in 2d if you want to merge horizontly then no of rows should be same and if veritically then no of column  should be same. Same goes for n-D array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually one of my function was returning scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix and I was converting it into np.array along with lists returned by another function so that I can merge all them but the sparse matrix was converted into 
array(<73194x17 sparse matrix of type '' with 203371 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object) 
which was not compatible with np.hstack.
so sorry for the inconvenience. 
I figured out my solution instead of numpy.hstack i used scipy hstack function.
Thank you, Everyone, for responding.